# Maximum number of intersections of two concave polynomials over a certain range

Tags: polynomials

Let's say I have two polynomials. They intersect at (0,0) and at (1,1) and I know that both functions are concave between these two points. I do not know the degree of either polynomial. Is there a maximum number of intersections between 0 and 1? If so, what is it?

I know that two polynomials have a maximum number of intersections n, where n is the higher order of the two polynomials. I also know that there are an infinite number of possible intersections between two concave functions, but I'm wondering if, given the constraints I have mentioned above, I could find the maximum number of intersections between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two polynomials $q_1$ and $q_2$ which have roots at $0$ and $1$, both, and which have $n$ intersections between $0$ and $1$.

Example (the intersections happen to be roots in this case):
$$
q_1(x) = -q_2(x) = x(x-1)
\left(x-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)
\left(x-\frac{2}{n+1}\right)
\cdots
\left(x-\frac{n}{n+1}\right)
$$
Let
$$
p_1(x) = q_1(x) + x + ax(1-x) \\
p_2(x) = q_2(x) + x + ax(1-x)
$$
with
$$
a = \max_{i\in\{1,2\}}\left(
\max_{x\in[0,1]} \left|q_i''(x)\right|
\right)
$$
This implies
$p_i''(x) = q_i''(x) -2a < 0 \;\; \forall x\in [0,1],$ which in turn means that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are concave.

This shows that you can have two polynomials with intersections at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, which are concave between those points and have any given number of intersections between those points.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would this stand if we were limited to integers as coefficients?

Comment: @Andrew If you multiply $q_1$ and $q_2$ with $(n+1)^n$ and also round $a$ towards the next integer, you get polynomials with integer coefficients. If you want [monic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial), just add $x^N(x-1)^N$ with a sufficiently large $N$ to the "integer versions" of $q_1$ and $q_2$ and recalculate $a$. The resulting new $p_1$ and $p_2$ will still pass through $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ and they will still have the same intersections.